# Should I use Realm Objective-C or Realm Swift in my mixed Objective-C / Swift project?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

My project uses Swift and targets iOS 8.0 and newer, but we use some files from our old Objective-C project, and brings in some Objective-C libraries via CocoaPods. Which Realm interface should I use in this project: Objective-C or Swift? I'm confused because of the announcement in the Realm documentation:

> If you’re looking to use Realm from Objective-C, or from mixed Objective-C & Swift apps please see Realm Objective-C instead.
>   Using both Realm Objective-C and Realm Swift simultaneously is not supported.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They key detail is whether you intend to access your Realm model classes from only Swift, or both Swift and Objective-C. If you will only access them from Swift you can happily use Realm Swift, even if elsewhere in your application you use code written in Objective-C. If you will access your Realm model classes from both Swift and Objective-C code you'll need to use Realm Objective-C rather than Realm Swift.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re looking to use Realm purely from Swift, you should consider using Realm Swift instead.
Using both Realm Objective-C and Realm Swift simultaneously is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use `Realm Swift` **only if you intend to use it from Swift** otherwise you should use `Realm Objective-C`. One of the reasons for this would be that at this point [`List` and `RealmOptional` properties aren’t accessible from Objective‑C](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#list-properties-arent-accessible-from-objective-c).