# Using Realm objective-c in a Objective-c - Swift mixed project

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm

What i read here [Should I use Realm Objective-C or Realm Swift in my mixed Objective-C / Swift project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328574/should-i-use-realm-objective-c-or-realm-swift-in-my-mixed-objective-c-swift-pr) is i should use Realm objective-c in a mixed project. (Swift and objective-c)

I tried it, i can begin transaction from swift code but i cant commit transactions. Then i looked st the .m file and see that commit transaction is not supported in swift.

am i missing something or using realm in a mixed project is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

To commit a write transaction with Realm Objective-C from Swift, you'll need to use the error-handling variant of [`-[RLMRealm commitWriteTransaction:]`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMRealm(im)commitWriteTransaction:).

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.beginWriteTransaction()
// perform mutating operations on Realm objects.
try! realm.commitWriteTransaction()
```

Comment: If you're using Swift 3, `defaultRealm()` becomes `default()`. Nothing else from this sample has changed.